# Is there a well-known mathematical symbol for a sequence of variable bindings?

Tags: notation

I know I can render the boolean expression
$$
\mathrm{all}(e_i.type = \mathsf{int})_{i \in 1..n}
$$
as
$$
\bigwedge_{i=1}^n e_i.type = \mathsf{int}
$$
and the boolean expression
$$
\mathrm{any}(e_i.type = \mathsf{int})_{i \in 1..n}
$$
as
$$
\bigvee_{i=1}^n e_i.type = \mathsf{int}
$$
and how to do similar expressions such as sums ($\Sigma$) and products ($\Pi$). But is there any way to render the following expression with one of those “big symbols”?
$$
  \mathrm{let}\;
  ((s_i', \xi_i) = \mathcal{S}\;s_i\;\xi_{i-1})_{i \in 1...n}\;\mathrm{in}\;(\mathsf{Block}\;s_1'\;...\;s_n')
$$
I’m doing a sequence of bindings. I’m not summing or multiplying or anding or oring....just binding. Is there a conventional way to show this sequence of bindings, perhaps one using a big symbol? Or is my notation as good as any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

$$(s'_i,\xi_i)\mathop{=}\limits_{i=1}^n\mathcal{S} s_i\xi_{i-1}$$

Comment: That's actually very cool. I had not seen it before. Will be using it, though.